# psexec error handling multiple computers

Tags: batch-file, psexec, errorlevel

Need some quick help, I can use the below batch script successfully with the proper messages which shows the connection as successful or unsuccessful against one servername, but whenever I use it in a loop, even the servers where I can't psexec to, show the connection as successful  Example given in the next script

```
@echo off

    verify >nul
     xcopy "c:\test" "\\servername\c$\temp\R1-x86" /S /E /C /Q /H  /Y  /Z /I >> hurray.txt   
     psexec \\%%i -d -e cmd
       if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' (
       echo servername  connection was a success! >> hurray.txt        
       ) else (
       echo servername connection failed with error %ERRORLEVEL% >>hurray.txt
       )
)
```

The below doesn't work, all servers echoes connection was a success!, the else part of the error handling is not read in the for loop script against multiple computers.. Can anyone help ?

```
@echo off

for /F %%i in (C:\server.txt) do (
     verify >nul
     xcopy "c:\test" "\\%%i\c$\temp\R1-x86" /S /E /C /Q /H  /Y  /Z /I >> hurray.txt   
     psexec \\%%i -d -e cmd
       if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' (
       echo %%i  connection was a success! >> hurray.txt        
       ) else (
       echo %%i connection failed with error %ERRORLEVEL% >>hurray.txt
       )
)
```

Comment: anyone please, can somebody help, setlocal enabledelayedexpension on the top of the for-loop script and then calling it via !errorlevel! doesn't work

Comment: Running `psexec` in a command prompt window without any parameters outputs a help with last paragraph being: **Error codes returned by PsExec are specific to the applications you execute, not PsExec**. So you don't get any information via `errorlevel` about success or failure to run the command on the remote machine from `psexcec`. You get the error/exit/return code assigned to `errorlevel` of the executed command if it could be executed at all on remote machine.

Comment: See the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) and use `if not errorlevel 1` in batch code for testing if the executed command exited with return code 0 or use `if errorlevel 1` to test if executed command exited with a return code greater or equal 1. That syntax is always better than comparing against environment variable `ERRORLEVEL` as working even in command blocks.